# Make Consul UI read-only

Tags: consul, consul-kv

We use Consul and we are willing to enforce that developers can alter it only using git2consul approach, to retain the history of property changes and maintain a backup.

In order to ensure that, we would like to make Consul Key-Value browser UI read-only. How could we achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Consul [Web UI](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/tree/master/ui) is an ember gui on-top of the [Consul API](https://www.consul.io/api/index.html), using the same methods as the tools using Consul. Therefore you should be able to configure the web UI using the [ACL system](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/acl.html) to restrict use to READ only on scopes needed.

There is a Github Issue talking about this here: https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/3399